# Filter a list processing attributes of the objects contained in the list

Tags: java

I have a list of objects of the class Person. Person has 2 attributes: String name, int points

My original list contains the following objects:

```
person1 = Person("Samuel", 5)
person2 = Person("Maria", 3)
person3 = Person("Samuel", 3)
person4 = Person("Maria", 6)
person5 = Person("Clara", 1)
```

I want to process my original list and get the following one:

```
person1 = Person("Samuel", 8)
person2 = Person("Maria", 9)
person3 = Person("Clara", 1);
```

So only objects with unique name are allowed. In case that one or more objects have the same name, the points of those objects have to be summed

Any idea how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static List<Person> mergeByName(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,
            Collectors.summingInt(Person::getPoints)))
                  .entrySet().stream()
                  .map(entry -> new Person(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```